# MUI Drawer, content sitting 'underneath' it, ignoring drawers width

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

[image]In this example,my Draw element sits ontop of the next content. Its like the drawer has no width?

If someone could shed some light, and point me in the direction of correct documentation to read, that would be great

```
use client';
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from './page.module.css'
import {Box, Drawer, Toolbar, Typography} from '@mui/material';

export default function Home() {
  return (
          <>
          <Box sx={{display:'flex', backgroundColor:'green', height:'100%', }}>  
          <Toolbar/>
          <Drawer variant='permanent' 
          sx={{width:'100%'}}
          >
          Set of Text ONe
          </Drawer>
          </Box>
          <Box>  
          <Typography>  
          Set of text two , an example
          </Typography>
          </Box>
          </>
  )
}
```

[image]